# CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 standard rsync filling cached ram while using nocache

Tags: memory, linux-networking, rsync

What I'm doing:

I have mounted a windows share on my server and every five minutes I move a 1.5GB file to it using this command:

```
nocache -n 4 rsync -a -W --bwlimit=20000 /mnt/share /file/location
```

I've read all sorts of things on what nocache should be doing, but in the end, it basically completely fills the cached ram and starts forcing things in the swap which is slowing down my server.

I have tried nocache -n 2, with defaults, without it, without the -W tag, but in the end it's basically the same result.  I have not been able to find a clean explanation of why somebody would want to use -n or what limits it should be used given from the limited reading all it does is force posix_fadvise to be called -n number of times before it's done.

Reference:  https://github.com/Feh/nocache/blob/master/README

Note, we had to build nocache on our server, and we aren't experts with such things, so maybe it's not working as intended, yet I'm not sure how I would test whether it is working correctly or not on our server.

**Edit1:** 
**@Brian** Right! I forgot, originally I was having the other computer drop the file onto the server through a share, but that was maxing out the bandwidth of both hard drives and I couldn't effectively figure out a way to have the windows server not copy the file using all the bandwidth, even with robocopy and the bandwidth flag or such.  This was causing everything on both computers to basically lock up for 10 seconds (BAD).

So then I moved to the rsync setup on my server doing it in reverse, having the server pull the file from the windows machine using the rsync with bwlimit which still slows the server down a tad, but nothing locks up.

I have tried using nice -n 20 with rsync, but not using it as it didn't play nice with nocache, but I'll look into ionice, although I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for.

**@Andrew**
I'm trying to resolve every five minutes rsync dropping my 3-4GB of free ram to 100MB, then only releasing 1-2GB when other cron jobs / development happens to need memory. I'll also look into dd as long as the system while using direct IO will still let everything else run smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried using `nice` and `ionice` to lower the priority so when it competes for resources with other tasks it loses more often?  Something like `nice -n 20 ionice -c 3 rsync -a -W --bwlimit=20000 /mnt/share /file/location`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  If all you're doing is trying to minimize cache usage you can use `dd direct if=...` (assuming Linux) and move the file using direct IO.  If that doesn't minimize cache usage, there's no effective way to do that for some reason - perhaps the file system implementation won't work without using the page cache.

Comment: Search the Internet for rsync patched to use Direct I/O. This should take care of the problem.